# Как вытащить значения RadioButton(ов) если они в цикле? (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, tkinter, radiobutton

Создаю опросник и в одно окно нужно засунуть хотя бы три вопроса по 5 Радиокнопок на каждый.
Проблема в том что при запуске он выводит значения радиокнопок только из последнего вопроса

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Radiobutton
from tkinter import Tk,Frame, Label, Button, StringVar, Entry, TOP
import tkinter as tk

class ChildWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Опросник")
        self.geometry('800x500+100+100')
        for i in range(3):
            lbl = Label(self, text=questions[i])
            lbl.pack()
            self.selected = IntVar()
            radio_button_1 = Radiobutton(self,text='Да',            value=1, variable=self.selected, command=self.information)
            radio_button_2 = Radiobutton(self,text='Скорее да',     value=2, variable=self.selected, command=self.information)
            radio_button_3 = Radiobutton(self,text='Ни нет, ни да', value=3, variable=self.selected, command=self.information)
            radio_button_4 = Radiobutton(self,text='Скорее нет',    value=4, variable=self.selected, command=self.information)
            radio_button_5 = Radiobutton(self,text='Нет',           value=5, variable=self.selected, command=self.information)
            radio_button_1.pack()  
            radio_button_2.pack()  
            radio_button_3.pack() 
            radio_button_4.pack() 
            radio_button_5.pack() 

    def information(self):
        n = self.selected.get()
        print(n)

questions = list()
questionString = [
        "1. Вопрос №1",
        "2. Вопрос №2",
        "3. Вопрос №3",]
for qStr in questionString:
    questions.append(qStr)

class Mainself(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Inquirer for you")
        self.geometry('600x300+100+150')
        lbl = Label(self, text="Здравствуйте, к вашему вниманию представлен опросник\n", font=("Arial Bold", 15))
        lbl.pack(side=TOP)
        n_lbl = Label(self, text="Введите ваше имя: ", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
        n_lbl.place(x=0,y=50)
        n_txt = Entry(self, width=30)
        n_txt.place(x=190,y=52)
        s_lbl = Label(self, text="Введите вашу фамилию: ", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
        s_lbl.place(x=0,y=100)
        s_txt = Entry(self, width=30)
        s_txt.place(x=190,y=102)
        btn = Button(self, text="Поехали!", background="#555",foreground="#ccc",padx="20",pady="8",font="16",  command=self.open_child_window)
        btn.place(x=220,y=140)

    def open_child_window(self):
        child_window = ChildWindow()
def main():
    application = Mainself()
    application.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Какие строчки этого кода выводят ответы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно не перезаписывать каждый раз `self.selected` в цикле новой переменной, а сделать список таких переменных, и потом из этого списка брать переменную, через метод `get` получать выбранное значение.

```
class ChildWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Опросник")
        self.geometry('800x500+100+100')
        self.selected = []
        for i in range(3):
            lbl = Label(self, text=questions[i])
            lbl.pack()
            var = IntVar()
            self.selected.append(var)
            radio_button_1 = Radiobutton(self,text='Да',            value=1, variable=var, command=self.information)
            radio_button_2 = Radiobutton(self,text='Скорее да',     value=2, variable=var, command=self.information)
            radio_button_3 = Radiobutton(self,text='Ни нет, ни да', value=3, variable=var, command=self.information)
            radio_button_4 = Radiobutton(self,text='Скорее нет',    value=4, variable=var, command=self.information)
            radio_button_5 = Radiobutton(self,text='Нет',           value=5, variable=var, command=self.information)
            radio_button_1.pack()  
            radio_button_2.pack()  
            radio_button_3.pack() 
            radio_button_4.pack() 
            radio_button_5.pack() 

    def information(self):
        for var in self.selected:
            print(var.get())
        print()
```